# docker login - error storing credentials - write permissions error

Tags: docker, authentication, credentials

I am running a `docker login` command as a part of the Bamboo build job. The command text is obtained by `aws ecr get-login` call and executed in a subshell.

This command fails with `Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: write permissions error` when ran as a part of the Bamboo build, but the exact same command ran in the Terminal on the Mac that is the build agent, it succeeds.

Using Terminal:

- `aws ecr get-login` succeeds and returns the `docker login` command text
- `docker login -u ... -p ... -e none ...` succeeds and logs in
- There is a record for the ECR URL in KeyChain
- There is an entry in `~/.docker/config.json`

Using Bamboo:

- `aws ecr get-login` succeeds and returns the `docker login` command text
- `docker login -u ... -p ... -e none ...` fails with the error above
- KeyChain record being made available to all applications makes no difference'
- `chmod 777 ~/.docker/config.json` makes no difference

Both the Bamboo build and the Terminal session happen under the same user - `builduser`. `whoami` is the same for both. `stat ~/.docker/config.json` is the same for both - writable for both.

Can you think of further ways of discovering the differences between the context Bamboo runs the build in and I do in the terminal? The error above, verbatim, related to `docker login` is nowhere to be found online.

Comment: What's the permission of the `~/.docker` directory?

Comment: Same as the `config.json` file.

Comment: Is `$DOCKER_CONFIG` defined when you run inside of Bamboo?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I had to remove my existing `~/.docker/config.json` file.  It would not overwrite or modify the one that I had.

Comment: `rm ~/.docker/config.json`

Comment: docker login -u "username" -p "password" docker.io   it works for me after rm ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: Just remove the {credsStore} setting in you config file

Comment: @Shtefan I think you are on to something there.  I have never seen this happen on Linux either.  Perhaps a difference in BSD?  I know some of the command line utilities work a little differently between BSD and Linux.

Answer (score 27):

Try running the `docker login` command as sudo. It worked for me.

Run this command : `sudo docker login`.

This will prompt you to enter your sudo password. After providing the password, the login command will run and you will be able to login successfully.

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me on WSL on windows

Comment: This worked, though I had a follow-on issue, so I had to `chown ~/.docker/config.json` back to my user afterwards.

Mac on 13.6 w/ messed up docker desktop install

Comment: This worked also for an user that had "credsStore": "desktop" in the config. I'm unable to find the root problem now.

Answer (score 8):

Install the following packages to solve this issue.

`sudo apt install gnupg2 pass`

Answer (score 7):

**The Problem**: you try to login into docker registry and unable to authenticate due to storing credentials error.

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, 
out: `Post "http://ipc/registry/credstore-updated": 
dial unix /var/root/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/backend.sock: 
connect: no such file or directory`
```

**Solution**: according to docker login [**documentation**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) you have several ways for storing user credentials, and using external store is a best practice and much more secure than keeping it under local configuration.

> **Credentials store**
>
> The Docker Engine can keep user credentials in an external credentials
> store, such as the native keychain of the operating system. Using an
> external store is more secure than storing credentials in the Docker
> configuration file.
>
> To use a credentials store, you need an external helper program to
> interact with a specific keychain or external store. Docker requires
> the helper program to be in the client’s host $PATH.
>
> This is the list of currently available credentials helpers and where
> you can download them from:
>
> D-Bus Secret Service:
> https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases Apple
> macOS keychain:
> https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases Microsoft
> Windows Credential Manager:
> https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases pass:
> https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases
>
> **By default, Docker looks for the native binary on each of the platforms, i.e. “osxkeychain” on macOS, “wincred” on windows, and “pass” on Linux**. A special case is that on Linux, Docker will fall back to the “secretservice” binary if it cannot find the “pass” binary. If none of these binaries are present, it stores the credentials (i.e. password) in base64 encoding in the config files described above.

**Example**: on macOS - specify the configuration on `$HOME/.docker/config.json` and insert osx keychain method, ( if you are already logged in run `docker logout` in order to remove credentials from the file and run `docker login` again )

```
vim ~/.docker/config.json

{
  "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while trying to use ECR to get a Docker container **running** within a Jenkins pipeline on an AWS EC2 instance with an IAM Instance Profile.  I found lots of information about creating, pushing, and pulling instances from ECR, but not running.

The goal is a Docker container with the specific Ruby and Ansible versions installed, with all the various dependencies like Gem files.

I found the following Jenkinsfile worked:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment { 
        DOCKER_CONFIG = "${WORKSPACE}/docker.config"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh("rm -rf ${DOCKER_CONFIG}")
                sh("eval \$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||')")
                withDockerContainer(args: '-v ${WORKSPACE}:/scripts -v ${HOME}/.aws:/root/.aws', image: 'image_name:latest') {
                    sh("ruby script.rb")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The Docker login command alters the .docker/config.json file, and it appears to fail in some cases with a write error.  My guess is that it cannot handle some combination of existing configuration in the file and errors out.  Using the DOCKER_CONFIG environment variable makes it create a new config file locally.
- Removing the ${DOCKER_CONFIG} directory may not be necessary, and could possibly take some extra time.  However, I think it might avoid the case where the credentials stored there are stale.
- This must be installed: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper
- I found the eval statement solution here: [Jenkins Amazon ECR: no basic auth credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733396/jenkins-amazon-ecr-no-basic-auth-credentials)

Answer (score 2):

Install the following package then try docker login again
`sudo apt install install gnupg2 pass`

If it still doesn't work, run the command with root privileges
`sudo docker login`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the file `docker-credential-osxkeychain`:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the simplest solution was to create config.json file under .docker directory inside the user home directory:

~/home/.docker/config.json

Then I copied the content of this file from the server from where i was able to login to the docker hub.

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "SOMEVALUE"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.06.1-ce (linux)"
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `.docker/config.json`

remove `"credsStore": "osxkeychain"` from the json and save.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution on web worked for me.

```
`sudo nano  ~/.docker/config.json`
```

2. Replace:- credsStore to **credStore**
3. `ctrl+o` to save and `ctrl+x` to exit -done

Answer (score 0):

My fix came from this [issue](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2682#issuecomment-675135899).

> It turns out you cannot Docker login via an elevated shell depending
> on your environment as it appears the credentials don't get passed
> through.

I was running these commands in PowerShell as admin; once I switched to a regular command prompt, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

docker service is not running, so first check whether the docker service is running or not, and then try to reset or remove credentials.

if you are using it with AWS credentials then don't forgot to add the "--profile XXX" option if required

```
aws ecr get-login-password --profile prod | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in wsl, but I solved using this:

```
.docker/config.json

remove "credsStore": "something" (In my case it was pointing towards the .exe which was not compatible)
```

after changes it should look like this

```
"credsStore": ""
```

save it and then run **docker login** again. Hope it helps.