# Jenkins Amazon ECR: no basic auth credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker, amazon-ecr

I'm not able to push ocker images to Amazon ECR with Jenkins Pipeline: I always get `no basic auth credentials` :-(

Here is my setup:

- Jenkins 2.46.2
- [Amazon ECR plugin 1.4](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+ECR)
- I've added AWS credentials `aws-jenkins` to Jenkins (tested locally and successfully pushed to AWS ECR)
- I've printed `/root/.dockercfg` to debug auth in my `Jenkinsfile`

Jenkinsfile:

```
stage("Docker") {
  dir(path) {
    docker.build("my-image:latest")
  }
  docker.withRegistry("https://<my-aws-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com", "ecr:eu-central-1:aws-jenkins") {
    sh "cat /root/.dockercfg" // debug
    docker.image("my-image:latest").push()
  }
}
```

Logs:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
Wrote authentication to /root/.dockercfg
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[docker-emotion-compilers] Running shell script
+ cat /root/.dockercfg
{"https://<my-aws-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com": {
  "auth": "[...]",
  "email": "nobody@example.com"
}}[Pipeline] sh
[docker-emotion-compilers] Running shell script
+ docker tag --force=true my-image:latest <my-aws-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-image:latest
Warning: '--force' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
[Pipeline] sh
[docker-emotion-compilers] Running shell script
+ docker push <my-aws-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-image:latest
The push refers to a repository [<my-aws-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-image]
e30bf54e0f87: Preparing
b9f2c30c0d28: Preparing
5defc95691fd: Preparing
295d6a056bfd: Preparing
no basic auth credentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE (2017-05-23):**
Here is the Jira issue:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44143

Comment: Is ecr:eu-central-1:<aws-jenkins-credentials> an AWS cred?

Comment: Yes. I updated my questions for clarity. I've created new AWS credentials in Jenkins and named it `aws-jenkins`.

Comment: I've added the Jira issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44143

Answer (score 3):

Even that it seems logical that docker.withRegistry will perform a login to ECR at start and logout when done, it is not performed.
Therefor you must install **awscli** and add ECR login command before you perform the push.

> sh("eval \$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||')")

See http://www.tikalk.com/devops/ecr-in-pipeline/ for detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

just remove or rename ***$HOME/.docker/config.json*** file from your local pc or cloud server. It will solve the ***no basic auth credentials*** issue.

**Follow the below step in your terminal:**

```
mv $HOME/.docker/config.json $HOME/.docker/config.json.backup
```