Error deploying rails app with Kamal: Docker login fails with exit status 256
I'm trying to deploy the rails app using Kamal, but the deployment fails during the docker login step with the following error:
    ERROR (SSHKit::Command::Failed): docker exit status: 256  
docker stdout: Nothing written  
docker stderr: WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.  
<3>WSL (170175) ERROR: UtilAcceptVsock:250: accept4 failed 110  
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: 

Environment Details

Rails version: 8.0
Ruby version: 3.3.3
Kamal version: 2.3.0
Server: Contabo VPS running Ubuntu
Local machine: Windows 11 with WSL2 and Docker Desktop

here is the deploy.yml
    service: writehub

image: ibunhabibu/writehub

servers:
  web:
    - 45.52.19.17

proxy:
  ssl: true
  host: writehub.cyou
  app_port: 3000

registry:
  username: ibunhabibu
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

env:
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    - POSTGRES_USER
    - GOOGLE_API
    - PIXABAY
    - OPEN_WEATHER

ssh:
  user: deployer

accessories:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    host: 45.52.19.17
    port: "127.0.0.1:5434:5434"
    env:
      clear:
        POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_DB: 'writehub_production'
      secret:
        - POSTGRES_USER
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD

Here is .env file
KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD='dckr_pat_dockercredentials'
POSTGRES_PASSWORD='Myverylongstringpswd'
POSTGRES_USER='postgres'
GOOGLE_API='GoogleApipasword'
PIXABAY='pixabaitoken'
OPEN_WEATHER='openweathertoken'

also here is .kamal/secrets
# Grab the registry password from ENV
KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
GOOGLE_API=$GOOGLE_API
PIXABAY=$PIXABAY
OPEN_WEATHER=$OPEN_WEATHER
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER

# Improve security by using a password manager. Never check config/master.key into git!
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(cat config/master.key)

How can I resolve this error during Kamal deployment? Any help would be greatly appreciated

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787779/docker-login-error-storing-credentials-write-permissions-error

Thank you for the link you gave me have the answer for my error.

I found the answer from this link Since I'm using wsl2 ubuntu
I navigated to the Ubuntu terminal using the following command
ibunhabibu@DESKTOP-RG3E4I0:/mnt/c/Users/projects/rails/writehub$ cd ~
ibunhabibu@DESKTOP-RG3E4I0:~$ cd .docker/
ibunhabibu@DESKTOP-RG3E4I0:~/.docker$ nano config.json

then I edited it from
{
  "credsStore": "desktop.exe"
}

to
{
  "credStore": "desktop.exe"
}

after removing s in credsStore the problems solved
